# Mathematical operations inside a xtabs() table in R

Tags: r

How can I sum two factor levels inside a table? For example, I'd like to sum versicolor + virginica in this case...

```
t1 <- xtabs(~Species, iris)

> t1
# Species
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#        50         50         50
```

and then remove versicolor and virginica, leaving the new level "sumV" and its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t1 <- xtabs(~Species, iris)

#Species
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#        50         50         50
```

Then sum the values you want and assign them to a new level:

```
t1["sumV"]  = t1["versicolor"] + t1["virginica"]

#    setosa versicolor  virginica       sumV
#        50         50         50        100
```

Finally remove the values that you don't want to keep:

```
t1[-c(2,3)]

#setosa   sumV 
#    50    100
```

Answer (score 3):

We can `transform` the dataset by changing the 'versicolor', and 'virginica' to a new value 'sumV' and then do the `xtabs`.

```
xtabs(~Species,transform(iris, Species= c('setosa', 
           'sumV')[(Species %in% c('versicolor', 'virginica'))+1L]))
#Species
#setosa   sumV 
#    50    100
```

Or as @Ananda Mahto suggested, we can use `replace` with `grep`

```
xtabs(~ Species, transform(iris, Species = 
  replace(as.character(Species), grepl("^v", Species), "sumV")))
```

Comment: @Nancy Thanks for the comment.  I was converting the TRUE/FALSE logical output to `c(2,1)` by adding by 1,  Using that index, we can change it to 'setosa' and 'sumV'

Comment: @akrun I see. Why do you use +1L instead of +1 for that? Doesn't adding 1 to a boolean do the same thing?

Comment: @Nancy In this case, it doesn't make much difference.  `1L` is an integer, so if we are using it for large datasets, there may be some efficiency (though I use it always by practise)

Comment: Variation on a theme: `xtabs(~ Species, transform(iris, Species = replace(as.character(Species), grepl("^v", Species), "sumV")))`

Comment: great solution @akrun!